# Python regex to match street name and house number

Tags: python, regex, matching

I have a regex which matches **street names** (see [demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/WRd1jx/7)) and I have a regex which matches possible **house numbers** in Germany (see [demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/p8Vpl8/1)). Each regex works perfectly fine. In the next step I want to combine both regex (street names + house number). In other words, I am looking for a regex which matches **both** street names and house numbers together.

I have prepared a [demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/WRd1jx/8) with examples. I know these examples are not complete if you compare it with the strict rules [here](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/), but it is enough for my use case.

Since regex is a rule based language, let me try to explain the rules in words:

- In Germany the street name can be basicaly every kind of name. There can be a `.` or `-` in between.
- The regex should match even with lower case characters
- The house numbers are in most cases sth. like `99` or `99a`. But I tried to be creative and added some additional possible examples

**My problem:**
I have solutions to each seperate case (see demo 1 and 2) but my problem is that I don't know how to combine two regex to one (see demo 3).

Working regex for [street names](https://regex101.com/r/WRd1jx/7):

```
^(?:[A-Z] \d|[^\W\d_]{2,}\.?)(?:[- '’][^\W\d_]+\.?)*$
```

Working regex for [house numbers](https://regex101.com/r/p8Vpl8/1):

```
^[1-9]\d{0,3} ?[a-zA-Z]?(?: ?[/-] ?[1-9]\d{0,3} ?[a-zA-Z]?)?$
```

Based on the regex shown above, how do I combine both of them in order to match my examples shown in [demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/WRd1jx/8)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining 2 regex into one:

```sh
^(?:[A-Z] \d|[^\W\d_]{2,}\.?)(?:[- '’][^\W\d_]+\.?)*\s+[1-9]\d{0,3} ?[a-zA-Z]?(?: ?[/-] ?[1-9]\d{0,3} ?[a-zA-Z]?)?$
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](http://%5E(?:%5BA-Z%5D%20%5Cd%7C%5B%5E%5CW%5Cd_%5D%7B2,%7D%5C.?)(?:%5B-%20%27%E2%80%99%5D%5B%5E%5CW%5Cd_%5D%20%5C.?)*%5Cs%20%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0,3%7D%20?%5Ba-zA-Z%5D?(?:%20?%5B/-%5D%20?%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0,3%7D%20?%5Ba-zA-Z%5D?)?$)